# Apply CSS upon query string - My code does not work, but why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup message "Your invitation has been sent" on this page: https://idio.ai/thank-you-webinar-testing-ground/?referralsent=true

What I'd like to achieve to only show this message when the URL has this query string on it

> ?referralsent=true

On the class ".message" there is a **display: none** by default which needs to be changed to **display: block** in case the query string is there.

Here is my script so far but it does not work and I can't figure out why.

```
function getParameterByName(referralsent, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    referralsent = referralsent.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + referralsent + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

if (getParameterByName('referralsent')) {
        var referralsent = getParameterByName('referralsent');
        // replace only if available
        jQuery('message').css('display', 'block');
    }
```

What is wrong here why is it not showing? Any ideas?

Comment: maybe its either  `jQuery('#message')` or `jQuery('.message')`. Edit, after looking at your html its `jQuery('.message')` your missing the `.` `<div class="message hide" id="messageUser">`

Comment: use removeClass()/addClass() , as you're using class .hide to hide the element and .show to show the element

Comment: @DilipBelgumpi addClass or removeClass had nothing to do with the problem that the op was facing

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are doing wrong on defining the jquery object. You said you have .message class then you should jQuery('.message') instead of jQuery('message')

```
if (getParameterByName('referralsent')) {
    var referralsent = getParameterByName('referralsent');
    // replace only if available
    jQuery('.message').css('display', 'block');
}
```

--Thanks

Comment: damn, you are correct. Just one little dot and the whole thing is not working. 
Thanks a lot for pointing it out :)